# Running firebase functions locally with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am using firebase functions and cloud firestore for my project. I want to just run the functions emulator and connect to the remote firestore instance.

1. I have exported GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the terminal
2. The application is initialised, and it works perfectly when deployed on cloud.
3. When I run it locally, the function execution stops when I call any firestore method, and it fails with a timeout.
4. When I start the emulator, it does recognize that a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable is set, and gives me the following warning:

   > functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /Users/###/###/###/###/###/###. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
5. This had been working fine on my previous mac. Can this be a bug with the latest firebase-tools?

My firebase-tools are at 8.2.0 (latest at this time)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: *"Can this be a bug with the latest firebase-tools?*" - could you go into more detail about what isn't working the way you expect?  That message just looks like a warning to me.

Comment: The function is not making a call to cloud firestore. The function just times out after the set 60 seconds. I see the same behaviour even when the firestore emulator is running.